# How can i print this on python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am using for loops. I get an input `n` and I have to print a square which has a side of the size `n`.

For example, with `n = 4`:

```
*******
*** ***
**   **
*     *
**   **
*** ***
*******
```

It looks weird, but the blank inside is the square; `n` (4) is the number of stars on the side of the blank square.

Comment: the *'s look weird it the post but each one is the lines firstlilne:7* secondline:6* thirdlline:4* forthline:2* fifthline:4* sixthline:6* seventhline:7*

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem? Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how many stars to print on each line, how many spaces in between, etc.? Can you think of a mathematical rule that tells you how many lines there are?

Comment: the first line 2n-1 star second 2n-2 thirk 2n-3... but i don't know how to insert blanks in the middle and print 7* 6* 4* 2* and go back to printing 4*

Comment: "i don't know how to insert blanks in the middle" Well, see if you can come up with a rule for how many stars go before the blanks, then for how many blanks there are, then for how many stars after the blanks. Then just print all of those things sequentially for the line. "and go back to printing 4*" think more about a rule that takes the line number as input, and gives you the number of stars as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to store *one quarter* of the pattern into a list. With that you will be able to mirror the pattern horizontally and vertically:

```
def square(n):
    lines = ['*' * (n - i) + " " * i for i in range(n)]
    for l in lines + lines[-2::-1]:
        print(l + l[::-1])
square(4)
```

Output:

```
********
***  ***
**    **
*      *
**    **
***  ***
********
```